# Workflow based on activity history subject

Tags: workflow, leads, tasks, activityhistory

I would like to be able to create a Workflow that updates a custom field on a Lead object with a timestamp containing the current date only when on that Lead there is a Task on the Activity History with the Subject "Call". Is this possible? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: My Best guess is Visual Workfow

Answer (score 0):

Copying from and expanding upon a similar answer I wrote [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227700/access-opportunity-fields-during-task-creation/227703#227703).

You cannot do parent updates from a Workflow Rule or Process Builder on the Task object in most cases (Account being a possible exception depending on your business logic). This is because the `WhatId` and `WhoId` fields (called Related To and Name in the user interface) are polymorphic and can point to many different objects.

For this reason, you have to go to either a Flow or Apex solution.

The basic logic is to inspect the `WhatId` to determine its type ('00Q' is the key prefix for an Lead, so a Process can have a criterion 'Related To Id starts with "OOQ"', or you can look at `What.Type` in Apex) and then perform a query (Apex) or lookup (Flow) to find the relevant Lead once you establish that you have a Lead Id. Over and above this, you'd add your specific logic around Task Subject.

I'd personally prefer to do this in an Apex trigger, because to me the Flow approach here is a little clumsy, but it's doable in Flow. You'd start a Process on Task update and have the Process inspect its `WhatId` to see if it's related to an Lead, and if so pass the Task's Id to an invoked Flow, which would implement the logic as above. I'm not an expert on Flow and Process optimization, but I see some potential bulkification concerns here, which again would push me towards an Apex solution.

Another option could be a [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) rollup of Task to Lead, perhaps rolling up the Last Created Date value where Subject `LIKE 'Call%'`.

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. I am not an expert on Flow or Apex myself. It will be so helpful if you can add a screenshot on how that Flow will look like since I was trying to replicate your answer myself and couldn't figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: @Alberto I've never actually built the Flow solution. I would always do this in a trigger myself.

Comment: Thanks David, in that case, just to have a better idea, would you mind sharing an example on how that trigger will look like. That will help me moving forward and experimenting with the Apex solution.